# KOMA: Header not produced on chapter start page when using abstract environment in chapter preamble

Tags: koma-script, abstract

I am using the document class `scrreprt` to set a chapter preamble (using `\setchapterpreamble{}`) as well as a header on the chapter start page. This usually works fine unless I introduce an `abstract` environment in the chapter preamble. In this case, no header is produced on the chapter start page, and no error is reported. Header is produced fine on the other pages. A MWE to reproduce the issue:

```
\documentclass[twocolumn,twoside,abstract=on]{scrreprt}
\usepackage{scrlayer-scrpage}
  \clearpairofpagestyles
  \newpairofpagestyles[scrheadings]{test999}{
  \KOMAoptions{headsepline=on}
  \KOMAoptions{plainheadsepline=on} 
  \lehead[plain.LEFT]{LEFT}
  \rehead[plain.RIGHT]{RIGHT}
  \lohead[plain.LEFT]{LEFT}
  \rohead[plain.RIGHT]{RIGHT}
  \cefoot{\pagemark} \cofoot{\pagemark}
  }

\pagestyle{test999}
\renewcommand*\chapterpagestyle{plain.test999}

\usepackage{fontspec}

\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}
  \setchapterpreamble{\begin{abstract} \lipsum[1] \end{abstract}}
  \chapter{one}
    \section{one.one}
    \lipsum
\end{document}
```

Replacing or removing the `abstract` environment from the chapter preamble in the above code results in the header being produced correctly on the chapter start page.

I can use the `quote` environment to get around this temporarily, but would appreciate any help for a long term solution as I prefer to use the `abstract` environment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It would be really better if you define a new environment. `scrreprt` uses option `titlepage=on` by default. With this option environment `abstract` excecutes `\titlepage` which includes a `\thispagestyle{empty}` ... If you set option `titlepage=off` the layout of the abstract changes.

While you could solve your problem by

```latex
\newcommand*{\originaltitlepage}{}
\let\originaltitlepage\titlepage
\renewcommand\titlepage{\originaltitlepage\thispagestyle{plain}}
```

or

```latex
\begin{abstract}\thispagestyle{plain} \lipsum[1] \end{abstract}
```

it is still a misuse of environment `abstract`.

---

Off topic: After `\pagestyle{test999}` the style name `headings` is an alias of `test999` and `plain` is an alias of `plain.test999`. If you do not want to use `plain.test999` as chapter page style with other pairs of page styles, you do not need to redefine `\chapterpagestyle`. Example:

```latex
\documentclass[twocolumn,twoside,abstract=on]{scrreprt}
\usepackage{scrlayer-scrpage}
  \clearpairofpagestyles
  \newpairofpagestyles[scrheadings]{test999}{
  \KOMAoptions{headsepline=on}
  \KOMAoptions{plainheadsepline=on} 
  \lehead[plain.LEFT]{LEFT}
  \rehead[plain.RIGHT]{RIGHT}
  \lohead[plain.LEFT]{LEFT}
  \rohead[plain.RIGHT]{RIGHT}
  \cefoot{\pagemark} \cofoot{\pagemark}
  }
\pagestyle{test999}

\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}
  %\setchapterpreamble{\begin{abstract}\thispagestyle{plain} \lipsum[1] \end{abstract}}
  \chapter{one}
    \section{one.one}
    \lipsum
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks. This helps! I think I will define my own custom abstract environment.